# Laravel 8.4 project on Heroku error 403 in Apache after Procfile

Tags: apache, heroku, laravel-8, http-status-code-403, procfile

I am deploying my first Laravel project using this guide: https://appdividend.com/2018/04/17/how-to-deploy-laravel-project-on-heroku/
I have made it up until step 9, in other words: I created a Procfile without file extension with `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`, generated and set the encryption key and successfully deployed the project.

However, when I visit the site, every page throws a 500 HTTP error displaying my custom error pages. This most definitely does not happen locally.
(I made one static page direct towards my custom 503 error page instead, so that GET request is normal.)

When I check the logs using PowerShell with `heroku logs --tail` I receive the following output:

```
2021-06-17T11:54:55.644540+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T11:54:55.644540+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T11:54:55.799446+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T11:54:55.799446+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T11:57:42.028071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=b9bfe3e2-82de-47af-bae4-1d6cbc4a206e fwd="my public IP" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-17T11:57:42.568855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=6e51df46-02e7-4d6d-b515-3fa1c4834613 fwd="my public IP" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-17T11:58:03.455474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=b61ff6e6-b904-486c-9624-a4b7d7804ae1 fwd="my public IP" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

2021-06-17T12:06:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:06:36.341144+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1e8d4442 by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:06:36.341144+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:06:36.351809+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:06:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-17T12:06:38.816708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `heroku-php-apache2`
2021-06-17T12:06:42.411923+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 536870912 Bytes of RAM
2021-06-17T12:06:42.443766+00:00 app[web.1]: PHP memory_limit is 128M Bytes
2021-06-17T12:06:42.456606+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting php-fpm with 4 workers...
2021-06-17T12:06:42.569696+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting httpd...
2021-06-17T12:06:42.707664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-17T12:06:52.248862+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=717e7ca1-d1da-4138-be09-5907e1700504 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=403 bytes=363 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:06:52.248875+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thu Jun 17 12:06:52.248017 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 154:tid 140377919043328] [client 10.41.181.68:21921] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
2021-06-17T12:06:52.249127+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.181.68 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:06:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:12:36.039961+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thu Jun 17 12:12:36.038943 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 153:tid 140377919043328] [client 10.11.176.31:24186] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
2021-06-17T12:12:36.040254+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.176.31 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:12:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:12:36.040292+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=588a07f2-6a82-4b19-be26-d99e86508e58 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=403 bytes=363 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:25:42.485188+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thu Jun 17 12:25:42.484171 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 155:tid 140377851950848] [client 10.41.171.6:11185] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
2021-06-17T12:25:42.485538+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.171.6 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:25:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:25:42.485879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=e5fc29bf-1833-4b1c-87f0-47def5e79f58 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=5ms status=403 bytes=363 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:25:49.358661+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thu Jun 17 12:25:49.357969 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 153:tid 140377784792832] [client 10.11.234.144:20872] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
2021-06-17T12:25:49.358970+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.234.144 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:25:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:25:49.359616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=869f8dbd-262f-4462-b7bf-73294987cb14 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=403 bytes=363 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:25:52.182757+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.234.144 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:25:52 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:25:52.183507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=aad7f101-8530-4270-8421-eb95038ad7f8 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=360 protocol=https

2021-06-17T12:33:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:34:07.641518+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:34:07.641518+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 30d06f26 by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:34:07.909412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-06-17T12:34:07.929249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-06-17T12:34:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-17T12:34:08.898217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-06-17T12:34:08.962065+00:00 app[web.1]: SIGTERM received, attempting graceful shutdown...
2021-06-17T12:34:08.962075+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping php-fpm...
2021-06-17T12:34:08.963414+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping httpd...
2021-06-17T12:34:08.966608+00:00 app[web.1]: Shutdown complete.
2021-06-17T12:34:09.018975+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-06-17T12:34:12.074660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`
2021-06-17T12:34:17.481627+00:00 app[web.1]: DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to 'public/'
2021-06-17T12:34:17.582367+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 536870912 Bytes of RAM
2021-06-17T12:34:17.619538+00:00 app[web.1]: PHP memory_limit is 128M Bytes
2021-06-17T12:34:17.639142+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting php-fpm with 4 workers...
2021-06-17T12:34:17.741847+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting httpd...
2021-06-17T12:34:18.057406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-17T12:34:40.311200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=c694d2d3-d81d-4956-a56a-5e437fdd25af fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=244ms status=500 bytes=2276 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:34:40.316794+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.167.33 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:34:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 2052 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:34:40.584831+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/javascript.js" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=c4e5457f-54d6-47ab-a49b-25d0f6847a33 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=392 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:34:40.590691+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.167.33 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:34:40 +0000] "GET /js/javascript.js HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:34:40.702186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/style.css" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=9966283b-2868-4eb0-99d4-ff23fcf3bf86 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=5614 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:34:40.707977+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.167.33 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:34:40 +0000] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5381 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:34:41.338600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/fonts/unispacefont/unispace_bd.woff2" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=abe1b487-b1d5-4e69-9ce3-522d71f273a4 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=19032 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:34:41.339220+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.246.133 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:34:41 +0000] "GET /fonts/unispacefont/unispace_bd.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 18796 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/css/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:34:41.342795+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.167.33 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:34:41 +0000] "GET /img/background.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 527193 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/css/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:34:41.364937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/img/background.gif" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=84347863-b933-4905-806f-cb845841382c fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=527430 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:34:41.758978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=6cdc7f4e-2f38-4eba-b68c-01007d056573 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=231 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:34:41.764926+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.145.208.41 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:34:41 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:18.999443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=c6fed9d7-927f-47d2-8b7d-d7ae778470ce fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=34ms status=500 bytes=2276 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:19.001120+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 2052 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:19.214613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/javascript.js" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=dddbe457-5c42-4690-b2bf-668f3fb6fa5b fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=392 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:19.216549+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:19 +0000] "GET /js/javascript.js HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:19.328406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/style.css" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=06c20f54-0efa-467f-a82c-8b0f31c236d1 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=129 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:19.330477+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:19 +0000] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:19.455017+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/img/background.gif" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=e4786017-356b-4e00-8407-9f5db00aca76 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=130 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:19.457067+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:19 +0000] "GET /img/background.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/css/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:20.794980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/profile" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=7e86eddf-c38f-4350-bc34-a9a21f96d6ce fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=2276 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:20.797031+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:20 +0000] "GET /profile HTTP/1.1" 500 2052 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:22.055940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assignments" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=2ba4e41b-c431-4658-b42e-719a47d38895 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=2276 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:22.057700+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:22 +0000] "GET /assignments HTTP/1.1" 500 2052 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/profile" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:22.916661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/motivatie" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=290562af-a18a-42b1-bd97-34007a70ae9b fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=2276 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:22.918708+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:22 +0000] "GET /motivatie HTTP/1.1" 500 2052 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/assignments" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:23.758614+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:23 +0000] "GET /beroepsbeeld HTTP/1.1" 500 2052 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/motivatie" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:38:23.759586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/beroepsbeeld" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=689a9d3c-5416-40de-9a4b-6a61ffefb786 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=500 bytes=2276 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:24.542760+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/error/503" host=[REDACTED].herokuapp.com request_id=8abe0728-5b95-4935-8dd3-3fd33e326f43 fwd="my public IP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=2276 protocol=https
2021-06-17T12:38:24.544759+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.238.239 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:38:24 +0000] "GET /error/503 HTTP/1.1" 500 2052 "https://[REDACTED].herokuapp.com/beroepsbeeld" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
2021-06-17T12:40:48.596106+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `php -a` by user [REDACTED]
2021-06-17T12:40:52.937251+00:00 heroku[run.9243]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-17T12:40:53.278275+00:00 heroku[run.9243]: Awaiting client
2021-06-17T12:40:53.311177+00:00 heroku[run.9243]: Starting process with command `php -a`
2021-06-17T12:41:46.949422+00:00 heroku[run.9243]: Process exited with status 255
2021-06-17T12:41:47.020869+00:00 heroku[run.9243]: State changed from up to complete
```

I honestly have no idea how to grant Heroku the access it wants.
I have successfully integrated the free pgsql database from Heroku into the project from step 11 and I am able to migrate both on the cloud and on the local copy. However, I am unable to seed on the cloud. I suspect this to be related to the issue above.

Class Faker/Factory not found error during seeding:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses a database, you might configure this first using step 10 and 11 of your tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, edited main thread. Unfortunately, that did not work and a new issue arose.